# Unable to fetch install referrer value from facebook live ads using deferred deep link

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, branch.io, install-referrer, attribution

I created deeplink from branch.io dashboard as mentioned [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/) and used the same deeplink in facebook ads.

I am able to get referrer value (utm_source and utm_campaign) when app is installed from the facebook ads preview (shown in facebook app notification) but not in case of live ads (ads shown in user's facebook feed).

In live ads,utm_source and utm_campaign are always not set.

Below is the string that I get from install referrer broadcast when app is installed and opened first time from facebook live ads which has deferred deeplink :

```
utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)
```

I am unable to fix this issue, what changes needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

this is Vatsal from Branch.

The new App Install integration Facebook Ads is facing issues with Branch deep links as deferred deep links. We have been working with FB to resolve the issue, but it seems to be blocked, unfortunately. Though it will not affect the attribution, the deferred deep linking will not work.

Apologies for the inconvenience. Please feel free to reach us at integrations@branch.io